# Functions com mesmo parametro

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho duas funções que são acionadas a partir do código do produto, minhas functions são utilizadas para completar os próximos campos, mas não posso utilizar join.

O correto seria criar um arquivo a parte  para a segunda função ja que elas utilizam o mesmo parametro ?

Ou tem como fazer num mesmo arquivo funções com parametros iguais porém que executem coisas distintas?

Abaixo vou deixar meu script do index

```html
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $("input[name='codigo_produto']").on("change", function(){
                var $descri = $("input[name='descri']");
                var $barcode = $("input[name='barcode']");
                var $id = $("input[name='id']");
                var $unid = $("select[name='unid']");
                var $familia = $("select[name='familia']");
                var $tipo = $("select[name='tipo']");
                var $id_depto = $("select[name='id_depto']");
                var $grupo = $("select[name='grupo']");
                var $cod_referencial = $("input[name='cod_referencial']");
                var $codigo_interno = $("input[name='codigo_interno']");
                var $embalagem = $("input[name='embalagem']");
                var $inativo = $("input[name='inativo']");                    

                $.getJSON('function_pro-1.php',{ 
                        codigo_produto: $( this ).val(),
                            executar : 1
                },function( json ){
                        $descri.val ( json.descri );
                        $barcode.val( json.barcode );
                        $id.val( json.id );
                        $unid.val( json.unid );
                        $familia.val( json.familia );
                        $tipo.val ( json.tipo );
                        $id_depto.val( json.id_depto );
                        $grupo.val( json.grupo );
                        $cod_referencial.val( json.cod_referencial );
                        $codigo_interno.val( json.codigo_interno );
                        $embalagem.prop('checked', !!+json.embalagem);
                        $inativo.prop('checked', !!+json.inativo );
                     
                        
                });
        });
});


$(document).ready(function(){
        $("input[name='codigo_produto']").on("change", function(){

                var $un_medida = $("input[name='un_medida']");
                var $operacao = $("input[name='operacao']");
                var $fator = $("input[name='fator']");
                var $default_venda = $("input[name='default_venda']");
                var $fator_carga = $("input[name='fator_carga']");
                
                $.getJSON('function_pro-1.php',{ 
                        convunid: $( this ).val(),
                        executar : 2
                },function( json ){

                        $un_medida.val ( json.un_medida );
                        $operacao.val ( json.operacao );
                        $fator.val ( json.fator );
                        $default_venda.val ( json.default_venda );
                        $fator_carga.val ( json.fator_carga );
                });
        });
});
```

function-1.php

```html
    <?php
include_once("conn.php");

$opc = isset($_GET['executar']) $_GET['executar'] : 0; 

function codigo_produto($codigo_produto, $conn){
    
    $result = "SELECT * FROM cadpro WHERE codigo_produto = '$codigo_produto' ";

    $resultado = $conn->query($result);

    // DECLARA A VARIAVEL
    $valores = array();

    if($resultado){
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
        $valores['descri'] = $row['descricao'];
        $valores['barcode'] = $row['barcode'];
        $valores['id'] = $row['id'];
        $valores['unid'] = $row['unidade'];
        $valores['familia'] = $row['familia'];
        $valores['tipo'] = $row['tipo'];
        $valores['id_depto'] = $row['id_depto'];
        $valores['grupo'] = $row['grupo'];
        $valores['cod_referencial'] = $row['cod_referencial'];
        $valores['codigo_interno'] = $row['codigo_interno'];
        $valores['embalagem'] = $row['embalagem'];
        $valores['inativo'] = $row['inativo'];
    } else {
        return json_encode(array( 'error' => mysqli_error($conn) ));        
    }

    return json_encode($valores);
    
}
if($opc === 1){
    echo codigo_produto($_GET['codigo_produto'], $conn);
 }else if($opc === 2){
    echo convunid($_GET['codigo_produto'], $conn);
 }else if($opc === 3){
    echo codigo_produto($_GET['codigo_produto'], $conn);
    echo convunid($_GET['codigo_produto'], $conn);
 }else{
    echo json_encode(array('msg' => 'opcao inválida'));
 }
//    if(isset($_GET['codigo_produto'])){
//        echo codigo_produto($_GET['codigo_produto'], $conn);
//    }
//    
function codigo($codigo_produto, $conn){

       $result = "SELECT * FROM CONVUNID WHERE codigo_produto = '$codigo_produto' ";

       $resultado = $conn->query($result);

       // DECLARA A VARIAVEL
       $valores = array();

       if($resultado){
           $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);

           $valores['un_medida'] = $row['un_medida'];
           $valores['operacao'] = $row['operacao'];                   
           $valores['fator'] = $row['fator'];
           $valores['default_venda'] = $row['default_venda'];
           $valores['fator_carga'] = $row['fator_carga'];

       } else {
           return json_encode(array( 'error' => mysqli_error($conn) ));        
       }

       return json_encode($valores);                
   }

    if($opc === 1){
    echo codigo_produto($_GET['codigo_produto'], $conn);
 }else if($opc === 2){
    echo convunid($_GET['codigo_produto'], $conn);
 }else if($opc === 3){
    echo codigo_produto($_GET['codigo_produto'], $conn);
    echo convunid($_GET['codigo_produto'], $conn);
 }else{
    echo json_encode(array('msg' => 'opcao inválida'));
 }
   
?>
```

Comment: Não entendi o problema

Comment: minhas functions são utilizadas para completar os próximos campos a partir do campo código do produto, mas não posso utilizar join, o correto seria criar um arquivo a parte ou tem como fazer num mesmo arquivo funções que executem a partir de um campo chave

Comment: Poderia explicar qual o problema?

Comment: no caso eu tenho duas funções para preencher campos a partir do código do produto, queria saber se existe a possibilidade de deixar as funções no mesmo arquivo ?  porém os parametros informados são os codigos do produto e ocorre conflito

Comment: Talvez se [edit] a pergunta acrescentando uma descrição melhor do tal conflito fique mais fácil pra quem for responder

Comment: @Bacco editei, ve se da para responder

Comment: Você pode ter N funções no mesmo arquivo não entendi o que dá conflito nem como

Comment: os parametros nas funcoes, repare que a funcao convunid tem o mesmo parametro da funcao codigo_produto, e isso conflita , mas se eu pego a mesma funcao e jogo em outro arquivo as duas funcionam, porém não queria criar 8 arquivos para cada função

Comment: Acho que entendi agora, vocâ precisa apena uma função e não as duas ao mesmo tempo certo? pq não manda um flag junto indicando qual delas usar.

Comment: no caso é assim, eu tenho produtos com conversões de unidade, aqui na empresa os produtos chegam por unidade e quilograma. ai para revender podem converter a unidade para caixa, grama, etc. Entao se o codigo do produto digitado tiver tanto registro na tabela cadpro que é referente a primeira função e registro na segunda convunid que é referente a convunid, ele teria que execuar as duas ao mesmo tempo

Comment: como fazer esse flag

Comment: Assim como você manda o código do ajax para o php pode mandar outra variável que diz qual função executar ou ambas. Por exemplo mande uma variável chamada executar os valores podem ser 1 => para `codigo_produto()` 2 => `convunid()` e 3 para ambas.

Comment: poderia me ajudar editando apenas a primeira função para meu entendimento ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie um flag dizendo qual função deve ser executada o primeiro passo é definir isso no javascript.

```
$.getJSON('function_pro-1.php',{ 
           codigo_produto: $(this).val(),
           executar: 1

//Código omitido
```

No php monte um if que lê esse flag e executa a função conforme o pedido.

```
$opc = isset($_GET['executar']) ? (int) $_GET['executar'] : 0;

if($opc === 1){
   echo codigo_produto($_GET['codigo_produto'], $conn);
}else if($opca === 2){
   echo convunid($_GET['codigo_produto'], $conn);
}else if($opc === 3){
   echo codigo_produto($_GET['codigo_produto'], $conn);
   echo convunid($_GET['codigo_produto'], $conn);
}
```

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67787/discussion-between-victor-and-rray).